# Repair Windows XP installation (0x000000ED and 0x0000007B)

Tags: windows-xp, bsod

I have an old Toshiba Tecra A3x portatil computer with Windows XP. I had to switch it off by unplugging the power cord after the SO hanged. Since then the computer doesn't start. It shows the awful blue screen of death instead with the code 0x000000ED:
[image: BSOD 0x000000ED]

I have tried to repair the installation using a Windows XP SP3 ISO image but I keep getting another error: 0x0000007B
[image: BSOD 0x0000007B]

The problem seems to be that Windows can not find the hard disk controller. I have read that changing the HDD mode in the BIOS does fix the problem, but my computer does not have such option:
[image: BIOS Page 1]
[image: BIOS Page 2]

I can mount the filesystem in Linux (Knoppix) and it seems to be ok. I have also tried to fix it with ntfsfix but nothing has worked.

These are some other things I have tried without success:

- Boot in safe mode
- Boot with the last working configuration

Can I pick your brain about how to fix this error?

Comment: Brutally switching off power for an old computer may cause the failure of some internal component. A repairman may help, or the computer might have reached end-of-life.

Comment: Why bother to (re)install an OS that is no longer supported? Try any Linux distro, Knoippix, if you,liked it, or another, such as Ubuntu. Try Linux from a live USB, and once you've decided you like it, install to the HDD.

Comment: @DrMoishePippik I totally agree with you, but the owner of this computer is a little long in the tooth to get used to a new desktop such as Linux.

Comment: @harrymc maybe you're right and the computer has reached EOL, but I can boot a Knoppix live from USB and everything seems to be ok.

Comment: It happens that one OS uses some function that the other doesn't, which is why one works but not the other. I can't tell from here what's the problem.

Answer (score 0):

If you believe the drive to be OK (may not be - may have errors) and further attempt to repair did not work, then your option with XP is to re-install XP.

Boot again with Linux as you did, recover the data to a USB connected HDD / SSD.

Once you have your needed data, re-install XP and recover the data you need.

You still may possibly find a disk drive error when you attempt to reinstall which means replacing the disk.

Good luck.